# docker-compose.yml: Why does restart "no" have to have quotation marks?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In the docker docs for docker-compose (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart) this restart options are given:

```
restart: "no"
restart: always
restart: on-failure
restart: unless-stopped
```

I'm just wondering, why the "no" has to be in quotation marks and the other options not? The docker-compose can't start with `no` without quotation marks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The reason is values `yes` and `no` are evaluated as `true` or `false`. That is why you need to use double quotes so that it is interpreted as string

Please see http://www.yaml.org/refcard.html

Comment: Strange to use it for this setting then.  Seems like "never" would have been a better choice.  Or just allow "no" as a boolean since it does seem to mean "false" here anyway.  Your answer is correct, just commenting that this feels like sloppy design.